# How do you get user input and then call a function with that user input in its name?

Tags: bash, shell

How do I write a bash script that asks the user for a number (1, 2 or 3) which is used to call a function with that number in its name? After that, the function then displays a message with the function number within it.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter a Number (1,2, or 3): " num

function foo() {
   echo This message is from function $1
}

foo $num
```

This is just a generic function that returns whatever the user inputs. I just don't know how to incorporate what the user inputs into the function name. Like if the user inputs 1, foo1 is called. If user inputs 2, foo2 is called. 3, foo3 is called etc. Is there a better way to do this other than using if else statements and writing three separate functions?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Numbers _alone_ don't make valid identifiers in function names. Let us know how the name will be with the number present

Answer (score 3):

Sure, there's no reason why you can't call a function whose name is a combination of a string literal and a variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo1() { echo 'hello from foo1!'; }
foo2() { echo 'hello from foo2!'; }
foo3() { echo 'hello from foo3!'; }

read -p "Enter a Number (1,2, or 3): " num

if [[ $num = [123] ]]; then # validate input
  foo"$num"
fi
```

Comment: Not to be picky, but that will work only with single digit index for the function. Might be better to use : if [[ $num =~ (1|2|3) ]]; then # validate input....what do you think ?

Comment: @Andre It was only meant to be a basic example of validation - if the OP really has `foo1`..`foo100` then I guess it would make more sense to check for a valid number in that range (or more likely, to rethink the overall approach). For the basic case in the question, I think `= [123]` is better than your regex (and if you _were_ going to use regex I would suggest `=~ ^[1-3]$` instead).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Enter Number:
read num

function1() { echo one; }
function2() { echo two; }

case $num in
    1)
        function$num
    ;; 
    2)
        function$num
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: You could use `1|2) function$num ;;` :)

Comment: My life is changed!